# MySQL query find, select multiple values and add new rows

Tags: sql, mysql

We have a table "catalog_category_entity_varchar" with columns "value", "entity_id", "store_id", "value_id" and "attribute_id".

Now we need to add new rows, copy the values from rows with "store_id" = 1 and replace "store_id" = with 3. Only the "value_id" can not be the same, because this is the row value_id.

So in screenshot below, it should add the following row;

```
12626  45  3  221  Monitoren
```

We already tried it with something like this, but that does not seems to be right;

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_varchar 
(
  SELECT value, entity_id, attribute_id, 3 AS store_id
  FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar
  WHERE store_id = 1
)
```

[image]

Comment: you don't appear to be selecting the columns in the the same ordinal positions as the columns in the table. ie the table is "value", "entity_id", "store_id", "value_id" and "attribute_id". but your select is value, entity_id, attribute_id, 3 AS store_id AND the insert should fail because the table has 5 columns but you are inserting without specifying the columns and inserting only four. AND the  column order in the published image is not the same as the table order. Please publish table definition and sample data as text.

Comment: To echo @P.Salmon, you should always explicitly list your columns rather than assume their order. It makes it much easier to right correct code and for you, or anyone else, to debug it. Plus, if the table is ever edited so that the column order changes then it won’t break your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `value_id` is a unique auto-increment column, this is how to do it :

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_varchar(value, entity_id, attribute_id, store_id)
SELECT value, entity_id, attribute_id, 3 AS store_id
FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar
WHERE store_id = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3F_WGnWI)

As mentioned in comments : You should specify the columns list for better clarity and readability of the code.

In your case, you must give the columns list because you are inserting four columns from a total of five.